# Show loading indicator during CanActivate

Tags: angular

In my **Angular** application I'm using a `CanActivate` guard to protect the access in certain router state.

The `CanActivate` guard performs a check that can last 3-4 seconds and it is very annoyng to wait that time without a loading indicator (i.e. a spinner).

Is there a "standard" way to show a loading spinner during the CanActivate check?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Nope. You need to write the code.

Comment: I like solution described at https://medium.com/javascript-everyday/angular-render-spinner-while-navigation-is-pending-f9e9ef910344

Answer (score 31):

To answer your question, there's no "standard" way to do this.

But it's easy. I solved this by doing the following:

Import AuthGuard service to your `app.component.ts` file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

// Import AuthGuard service here - double check the path
import { AuthGuard } from './services/auth.guard';

@Component({
    selector: 'body',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    // Inject AuthGuard service here
    constructor(private authGuard: AuthGuard) { }

    ngOnInit() { }
});
```

Add the loader HTML to your `app.component.html` file:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<div class="central-loader" *ngIf="(authGuard.loader)"><div><i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner"></i>&nbsp; Loading...</div></div>
```

Notice the `*ngIf` in the loader HTML above. This checks the `authGuard.loader` variable, and loads this HTML code if the value of this variable is set to `true`.

In the AuthGuard file (`services/auth.guard.ts` in my case):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    private loader$ = new Subject<boolean>();
    public loader = false;

    constructor() { 
        this.loader$.debounceTime(300).subscribe(loader => {
            this.loader = loader;
        });
    }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        this.loader$.next(true);

        // Returning an Observable for async checks
        return new Observable<boolean>(obs => {
            // Sample 2 second async request
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.loader$.next(false);
                obs.next(true);
                obs.complete();
            }, 2000);
        });

    }
}
```

You can also directly call `loader$` in the template with `async` pipe, eg:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<div class="central-loader" *ngIf="(authGuard.loader$ | async)"><div><i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner"></i>&nbsp; Loading...</div></div>
```

(Set `loader$` to public in this case).

But I don't want this loader to show up if the canActivate check completes in less than 300ms, which is why I am subscribing instead to the `loader$` with `debounceTime()`.

I understand that even sending `false` to the observer will be delayed by 300ms too, but that's okay for me.

By the way, this is the CSS I used for the loader, center both horizontal and vertical with full page blocking overlay:

```
.central-loader {
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1050;
}

.central-loader > div {
    height: 42px;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px #faf2cc solid;
    color: #8a6d3b;
    background-color: #fcf8e3;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Don't forget to import AuthGuard in `app.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

....

// Import AuthGuard service here - double check the path
import { AuthGuard } from './services/auth.guard';

@NgModule({
    ....
    providers: [
        AuthGuard,
        ....
    ],
    ....
});
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 26):

Try this, Using router events.
Its simple.

```
<div class="loading-icon" *ngIf="loading"></div>
```

and in the `app.component.ts` file:

```
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof GuardsCheckStart) {
        this.loading = true;
        console.log("GuardStart")
      }     
      if (event instanceof GuardsCheckEnd || event instanceof NavigationCancel) {
        this.loading = false;
        console.log("GuardEnd")
      } 
    });
```

Comment: From my point of view this is the best answer since it doesn't depend on the actual guard service. Background: If you have multiple guards you would have to depend on all of them in @James A solution.

Comment: Simple and working, this is a better answer.

Comment: There is one error in this code. When the Guard is cancelling the navigation GuardsCheckEnd is not called. Instead NavigationCancel is triggered.

Comment: @Seega To hide the loading, GuardsCheckEnd is enough since we will be having a fallback route after navigation cancel and that will trigger GuardsCheckEnd. But if you need to do something on cancel too, we can change it to if(event instanceof GuardsCheckEnd || event instanceof NavigationCancel) { console.log("GuardEnd")  }

Comment: @dp_t I was just running into this problem and wanted to mention it. You can decide if you want to add it to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hello after a while of looking around I found this, use the start with and tap this is used as the CanActivate Guard is loading.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, startWith, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { User } from './user';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  user: Observable<User>;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
              private db: AngularFirestore) {

      //// Get auth data, then get firestore user document || null
      this.user = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
        switchMap(user => {
          if (user) {
            return this.db.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges()
          } else {
            return of(null)
          }
        }),
        // Add these lines to set/read the user data to local storage
        tap(user => localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user))),
        startWith(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')))
      )
  }
}
```

See the "tap" & "startWith" functions saved me, use something like this if you are having loading problems. 
Some of those other comments are extremely hacky (Don't do hacky)